# Android Architecture Components runtime permissions

Tags: android, architecture, permissions, runtime, components

I'm using in my application Data Binding Library and ViewModel from Architecture Components. Methods from ViewModel are bound to buttons by annotations in layout file (e.g.:

```
android:onClick="@{exampleViewModel::actionToExecute}"
```

The problem is that actionToExecute requires runtime permission, and for fetching runtime permission I need Activity. How can ask for permissions from my ModelView?

Comment: Why is a `ViewModel` handling click events?

Comment: It is according to patterns in Data Binding Library, where you execute events by annotations as presented in example.
You can look at example described here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html#data-binding-for-events-via-listener-bindings-and-method-references

Comment: Your link is to a presenter, not to a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Why does it matter? It's the case where methods from object that is not activity (VM or presenter), are being called from annotation in layout.

Comment: "Why does it matter?" -- because handing click events is not the responsibility of a `ViewModel`. A presenter knows its activity and can therefore delegate the permission-requesting logic to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare A ViewModel handles clicks: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Comment: There is nothing on that page that says that a `ViewModel` handles user input events.

Comment: model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener(item -> {
            model.select(item);
        });